# Docker port mapping host not listening

Tags: docker, portforwarding

I have a docker container where the port mapping doesn't work anymore. On the host:

```
3b0d28970e58        docker.software-univention.de/zammad-zammad-nginx:3.6.0-42           "/docker-entrypoint.…"   24 minutes ago      Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:40001->80/tcp   zammad_zammad-nginx_1
```

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:40001
curl: (56) Recv failure: Die Verbindung wurde vom Kommunikationspartner zurückgesetzt 

curl http://172.16.0.249:40001
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.16.0.249 port 40001: Keine Route zum Zielrechner

ping 172.16.0.249
PING 172.16.0.249 (172.16.0.249) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.0.249: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms

nmap -sS 172.16.0.249

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-19 21:02 CEST
Nmap scan report for ucs-intranet.redacion.net (172.16.0.249)
Host is up (0.000018s latency).
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
... no 40001 entry in list

netstat -tulpen | grep 40001
tcp6       0      0 :::40001                :::*                    LISTEN      0          1019188    18819/docker-proxy

nmap -6 -sS ::1

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-19 21:10 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (::1)
Host is up (0.000028s latency).
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
... no 40001 entry in list

curl http://[::1]:40001
curl: (56) Recv failure: Die Verbindung wurde vom Kommunikationspartner zurückgesetzt

ping6 ::1
PING ::1(::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms
```

In docker container

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:80
<!DOCTYPE html>
curl http://172.16.0.6:80
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

Has anyone an idea what's wrong here? OS is latest UCS 4 (Debian based).

Best regards,

Alex

Comment: Do you have any firewall in your host OS?

Comment: No I don't think. Other Containers works well.

Comment: I run `docker network connect bridge zammad_zammad-nginx_1`and port forwarding works but outgoing connections from docker to an internet host doesn't work. Normally the container is only in this network `ad86dcb23150        zammad_appcenter_net   bridge              local` So could it be a problem with the docker network?

Comment: Run this image with default command, like `docker run -dp40001:80 zammad_zammad-nginx_1`. Do you run it via `docker-compose`?

Comment: Th container is part of an ucs-application. I already asked my question in their forum  a few weeks ago but didn't get an answer. I also removed and reinstalled the application. How the docker container gets created I cannot say. There is an docker-composer.yml file. docker run doesn't work there is no container template.